# How to get the limit bound for a specific value from an array in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

I have an Array

`val bins = Array(0,100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000)`

and here is my peice of code:

```
      private var cumulativeDelay:Map[String ,Double] = linkIds.zip(freeFlowDelay).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(l => l.map(_._2).sum)
      private var cumulativeCapacity:Map[String , Double] = linkIds.zip(linkCapacity).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(l => l.map(_._2).sum)

    cumulativeCapacity foreach {
      case(linkId , capacity) => {
          val rangeToValue = bins.zip(bins.tail)
             .collectFirst { case (left, right) if capacity >= left && capacity <= right =>
              Map(s"$left-$right" -> cumulativeDelay.get(linkId))
                }
       .getOrElse(Map.empty[String, Double])
      }
    }
```

So value of `rangeToValue` is coming like Map(1000-2000 -> Some(625)) but I want rangeToValue:Map[String,Double] = (1000-2000 -> 625)

Comment: You can partition the Array into two: first containing values smaller than your x, second one containing those bigger and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this, but it doesn't work with values out of range:

```
val bins = Array(0, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000)

val effectiveValue = 625

val rangeToValue = bins.zip(bins.tail)
  .collectFirst { case (left, right) if effectiveValue >= left && effectiveValue <= right =>
    Map(s"$left-$right" -> effectiveValue)
  }
  .getOrElse(Map.empty[String, Int])

rangeToValue("500-1000")
```

Comment: Hi @mkUltra, thanks for your solution but rangeToValue is coming like:  Map(500-1000 -> Some(625)) but i need like Map(500-1000 -> 625)

Comment: Are you sure to call 'apply' of rangeToValue  and not 'get'? rangeToValue("500-1000") should return 625, rangeToValue.get("500-1000") return Some(625)

Comment: Yes I am sure. And i want to store the value in  val rangeToValue:[String,Double]

Comment: Will you able to update question with piece of your code?

Comment: cumulativeDelay.get returns Option, just use cumulativeDelay(linkId)

Comment: Yes. Its working returning like Map(1000-2000 -> 0.499915) but when try to return rangeToValue("1000-2000")  i get an exception like java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1000-2000

Comment: I have one double, That what if same keys have different values like ("1000-2000"->1145) and (1000-2000 -> 1500). Could it be possible to have different values for same key. If not that how can I store values

Comment: Take a look at default values for Map in Scala.